# How to set visibility of graphic object defined within a custom function?

Tags: matlab, function, visibility

i'm still very new to matlab and as a training i'm trying to write a simple function that will plot a coordinate system centered at a specified position.

So far the relevant part of the function looks like this (skipped the calculation part for the center of the coordinate system):

```
function [] = fancyAxis(x,y,z,lengthX,lengthY,lengthZ,vis)

if vis == 1
    vis = 'on';
else
    vis = 'off';
end


%X-Achse
h_xAchse = plot3([x x],[Y1 Y2], [z z],'linestyle','--','visible',vis);
%Y-Achse
h_yAchse=plot3([x x],[y y], [z Z2],'linestyle','--','visible',vis);
```

The function works fine and stuff. But now I want to control the visibility of my function. So when calling it in a different script I want to be able to set the visibility off again. So I tried it with changing the "vis" constant but that won't work at all :(
So could someone pls give me a hint on how to do it correctly?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the axis and the play with them. Change the function call to

```
function [h_xAchse,h_yAchse] = fancyAxis(x,y,z,lengthX,lengthY,lengthZ,vis)
```

And then in your main code you can do:

```
[~,h_yAchse] = fancyAxis(x,y,z,lengthX,lengthY,lengthZ,vis)
set(h_yAchse,'visible','off')
```

You need the handles to be able to change the properties.

Comment: After combining all handles into one it works perfectly the way I wanted it :) Thanks for the fast reply and the help :)

Comment: @SirBando Im glad! consider accepting the answer as valid ;)